# Hashmap remove and update python

Tags: python, hashmap

I already have asked about hashmap before but in java, this time in python. I am wondering of how to remove the last entry or the last input by the user then update it to replace the removed entry to a new one that user will input here is my code

```
students = {}

for i in range(3):
    input1 = input("Enter student number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")
    input2 = input("Enter first name " + str(i + 1) + ": ")
    students.update({input1: input2})
    
print("Student List: ")

for x , y in students.items():
    print(x , y)
```

What I've got so far is to add all the user inputs into the map, now my only problem is to remove and update the last entry. Remove the last one then update/replace with a new one that the user is going to input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python version > 3.7 then you can use `students.popitem()` to remove the last item from the hashmap. If not you have to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Yep, I am using 3.7. will it remove the last one? Can I also add another one to replace the one that was removed?

Comment: Yes it will remove on basis of LIFO (Last in First Out). Hashmaps are dynamic in nature, you can add or remove as many as you want.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the idea. Appreciate it!!